# Does TOR protect against an attacker who knows your IP / physical location?

Tags: anonymity

I know that TOR protects me against de-anonymization by the websites / services I use. However If an attacker knows my physical location can I use TOR to hide the fact that I visit certain websites / services?

Comment: perhaps an interesting link for you: https://www.eff.org/pages/tor-and-https

Answer (score 1):

What tor can NOT protect against is monitoring and rogue software installed on your computer. If there is no monitoring software or viruses on your computer, then someone monitoring your internet connection at your physical location can of  course distinguish you are using tor, but will not be able to tell what websites you are visiting through tor.

Answer (score 1):

Attacker hack your device direct. This is based on your device. Link below. Question Asked should be the same answer for you. Above answer do not want to repeat. Same for VPN/ tor other networks.

[Could someone hack a tails device based on the firmware in it?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/11783/could-someone-hack-a-tails-device-based-on-the-firmware-in-it)

After attack consider links

Exfiltrate data from computers using speakers and headphones.

https://www.trendmicro.com/vinfo/us/security/news/vulnerabilities-and-exploits/mosquito-attack-shows-how-malware-can-exfiltrate-data-via-pc-speakers

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the entire data going via Tor is encrypted. So, if the attacker just sits in front of their computer and does not go to your home, they does not know what sites you visit via Tor. But, unfortunately, you are in a big trouble, if someone (a criminal, or a government agent, etc.) wants to [enforce you to say your secrets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber-hose_cryptanalysis). I hope it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Tor can't protect. If they know your physical location (usually obtained by mobile GPS, IMEI Tracking), high possibility that your internet line and Router is hacked.they stay in memory sends data to attacker. Tor, Tails, any OS won't stop them. It is easy to identify Tor user but hard to prove the traffic is belong to the target(as an evidence to be provided to a court) even they know you are using tor and snooping your computer screen. In short, you are not protected.